# How can my Python program avoid "PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied" when symlinking files in "C:\Program Files"

Tags: python-3.x, windows, permission-denied

I'm running out of space on my C: drive, a 256GB SSD.

I started looking for a way to move the files in "C:\Program Files" and "C:\Program Files (x86)" to another disk. After googling (forever), I decided to write my own Python program that would copy the files from those directories to the destination drive and leave symlinks at the original locations. Since the files won't technically be moving, Windows should not care.

After testing, I began trying to actually move files from "C:\Program Files (x86)". I moved a couple of subdirectories to the roomier drive and nothing seemed amiss. Even WinMerge said the moved directories were identical to their originals, which should mean the symlinks are functional.

Precautions:

- The Python program is run under my account from cmd.exe "as administrator" to avoid privilege errors.
- The computer has been placed in Safe Mode to avoid problems trying to move programs that might be running.
- My user account has Administrator privileges.
- Controlled folder access is OFF in Settings/Virus & threat protection.

In spite of these precautions, when attempting to move another directory from (x86), Calibre2, I am receiving 10 errors similar to the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\symmer.py", line 254, in _mv
    os.remove(ps)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Calibre2\\app\\bin\\api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll'
```

The errors are not all .dlls. There are 7 errors about .dlls, 1 .xml file, 1 .pak file, and an exe. But they are all [WinError 5].

The relevant Python 3.10.2 code is straightforward:

```
# Copy source file to destination if not there.
if not Path(dpath).exists():
    shutil.copyfile(ps, dpath)
# Delete source file from its directory.
os.remove(ps)
# Create a symlink in the source file's directory to dpath.
# Program needs to run "as admin" on Windows.
os.symlink(dpath, ps)
```

So the remove() is failing because Windows is denying access. I don't see how that is possible given the precautions above. Must I run the program directly from the Administrator account to avoid the error? That would be a problem since I'm pretty sure I never gave that account a password when I installed Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Some programs run even in safe mode. You could try to find any services that might be using those files and stop them, but that might not be enough. Like you said, the problem is deletion, so I would recommend copying rather than deleting. Then, you can create a bootable Windows USB drive and boot from that, to finish the deletion and create the symlinks. (You might be able to use a Linux USB drive, but some of them don't support NTFS by default)